# MySQL SUM() giving unexpected answer

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT
          t.amount
        FROM
          transactions t
        JOIN contracts c ON t.contractId = c.id
        JOIN insertions i ON c.id = i.contractId
        JOIN magazines m ON i.magazineId = m.id
        WHERE m.id = 26
          AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
          AND t.`timestamp` >= '2013-09-12'
          AND t.`timestamp` <= date_add('2013-09-12',interval 1 month)
        GROUP BY 
          t.id;
```

Which yields:

```
1100
800
1025
500
1200
552
395
395
1170
1000
675
```

I want only the SUM of this result.  I expect 8812.

So I use the following SQL:

```
SELECT
          IFNULL(SUM(t.amount),0)
        FROM
          transactions t
        JOIN contracts c ON t.contractId = c.id
        JOIN insertions i ON c.id = i.contractId
        JOIN magazines m ON i.magazineId = m.id
        WHERE m.id = 26
          AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
          AND t.`timestamp` >= '2013-09-12'
          AND t.`timestamp` <= date_add('2013-09-12',interval 1 month)
        GROUP BY 
          t.id;
```

And this is my result:

```
39600
9600
61500
9000
43200
49680
14220
5925
7020
36000
72900
```

????

Comment: Your `group by` usage is invalid. Please read this: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/ to understand why.

Comment: The issue is groupBy clause. Remove it and the query should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your original query.  It is not doing what you think it is doing.  You are aggregating by `t.id`, but selecting `t.amount`.  That means that MySQL is choosing an arbitrary value.

Why is this happening?  One possibility is that the following *is* the right amount for each transaction:

```
    SELECT sum(t.amount)
    FROM transactions t
    JOIN contracts c ON t.contractId = c.id
    JOIN insertions i ON c.id = i.contractId
    JOIN magazines m ON i.magazineId = m.id
    WHERE m.id = 26
      AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
      AND t.`timestamp` >= '2013-09-12'
      AND t.`timestamp` <= date_add('2013-09-12',interval 1 month)
    GROUP BY t.id;
```

If so, just removing the `group by` will give the right total.

Another possibility is that the `join`s are multiplying the rows.  My suspicion would be `insertions`.  If that is the case, then `t.amount` is being repeated and the query you want would choose just one value:

```
    SELECT min(t.amount)
    FROM transactions t
    JOIN contracts c ON t.contractId = c.id
    JOIN insertions i ON c.id = i.contractId
    JOIN magazines m ON i.magazineId = m.id
    WHERE m.id = 26
      AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
      AND t.`timestamp` >= '2013-09-12'
      AND t.`timestamp` <= date_add('2013-09-12',interval 1 month)
    GROUP BY t.id;
```

If this is the problem, then to get the full sum, you can use a sub-query:

```
select sum(amount)
from (SELECT min(t.amount) as amount
      FROM transactions t
      JOIN contracts c ON t.contractId = c.id
      JOIN insertions i ON c.id = i.contractId
      JOIN magazines m ON i.magazineId = m.id
      WHERE m.id = 26
        AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
        AND t.`timestamp` >= '2013-09-12'
        AND t.`timestamp` <= date_add('2013-09-12',interval 1 month)
      GROUP BY t.id
     ) t
```

Comment: Yes, that was it.  It was insertions that was causing duplicates.  This has solved it.  I was reading the other guy's articles but I just wasn't grokking it.  I understand what you have done tho.  Thank you.